# Searching a 3d array for the nearest "cell" that has a specific value - python

Tags: python, arrays

**Please, Note that I am new to stack-overflow and may get some technicalities a bit wrong. If I do, please point them out**

I have been writing a program that is intended to model how a disease (influenza) will spread though a population for my a-level NEA. A lot of it is built around a 3D array that represents many parts about a town with the 2 dimensions acting like a grid view (similar to chess or civilization 4 etc) and the 3rd storing information about the 2D cell (for example the first value per 2d cell is the population, second is the type of area, 3rd is the amount infected etc). Part of the code that represents the people moving from cell to cell, needs to know where the nearest 2D cell is that contains a certain value within the 3rd dimension of it. In practice this will essentially tell the computer where the nearest place for work/entertainment is.

For example in an array such as a 4 by 4 by 4 array, all with 0s except random 1s (I'm using integers in my program because they'll be more than 2 possibilities in final product), it will go though each 2D cell and find the nearest 1 in the second value in the 3rd dimension to the 2d cell it is currently on, store it in the array , then move to the next.

Here is my code so far:(everything before the subroutine will be different in final)

```
townLayout=[[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]]]

import random

b=0
while b<5:
    i=0
    while i<5:#double loop to create 2 dimentions
        townLayout[b][i]=[0,ran.ranint(1,4),0,0,0,15,15,0,15,15,0]
        i+=1
    b+=1
def nearestWork(townLayout):#anitate
    b=0
    isThere=True
    while b<5 and isThere==True:
        i=0
        xc=15
        yc=15
        dxc=15
        dx=15
        dyc=15
        dy=15
        while i<5 and isThere=True:
            multiple=False
            x=0
            isThere=False
            while x<5:
                y=0
                while y<5:
                    if townLayout[b][i][1]==4:
                        isThere=True
                        if xc>=b:
                            dxc=xc-b
                        else:
                            dxc=b-xc
                        if yc>=i:
                            dyc=yc-b
                        else:
                            dyc=b-yc
                        if x>=b:
                            dx=x-b
                        else:
                            dx=b-x
                        if y>=b:
                            dy=y-b
                        else:
                            dy=b-y
                        if (dx+dy)<(dxc+dyc):
                            xc=x
                            yc=y
                        elif (dx+dy)==(dxc+dyc):
                            Multiple=True
                    y+=1
                x+=1
            if isThere==True:
                townLayout[b][i][8]=xc
                townLayout[b][i][9]=yc
            else:
                print('no places of work detected')
                break
            if Multiple==True:
                townLayout[b][i][10]=1
            i+=1
        b+=1
    return townLayout
```

Is there a way to make this more efficient? will it work?